# SpotBugsRunAnalysis in Maven@3 requires report of agrregator sub-module which contains no source

Tags: azure, azure-devops, maven-plugin, multi-module, spotbugs

I do use Jacoco configured for a multi-module project. That means, that I have create an additional module `'code-coverage-report'` to aggregate the reports of all other sub-modules.

This new module (code-coverage-report) does only contain a pom.xml and no /src directory.

For my pipeline build I do use following Maven@3 task:

```
        - task: Maven@3
          inputs:
            mavenPomFile: pom.xml
            ...
            checkstyleAnalysisEnabled: true
            pmdAnalysisEnabled: true
            spotBugsRunAnalysis: true
```

But I do get following error when the build is running:

```
##[error]cp failed
cp: no such file or directory: /agent/_work/8/s/code-coverage-report/target/spotbugsXml.xml
```

What I have tried is to specify the skip property as true in my code-coverage-report submodules pom.xml

```
<properties>    
<spotbugs.skip>true</spotbugs.skip>
</properties>
```

but it got ignored.

I also tried to additionaly specify the `spotbugs-maven-plugin` with <`failOnError>false</failOnError>` in my code-coverage-report pom.xml, but also was not sucessful.

The odd thing is, that I have a different multi-module project that is configured in the same way and does use the same pipeline `Maven@3` task and this one works fine.

What could be wrong? What do I miss?

Comment: The `spotbugsXml.xml` error is not reported on my side with same task. Have you checked the detail command executed from pipeline log(it's `mvn.cmd -f D:\a\1\s\pom.xml clean test checkstyle:checkstyle pmd:pmd spotbugs:spotbugs` on my side), you can run the command locally first for troubleshooting, is it working on local? You can follow the [link](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/MavenMultiModule) to check the pom.xml.

Comment: Hi @Splioo, may i know if there's any update? Does the command work locally?